# Console route in Zend3 is not matching

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I have a console route in my module.config.php file

```
'console' => [
        'router' => [
            'routes' => [
                'remove' => [
                    'type'    => 'simple',
                    'options' => [
                        'route'    => 'remove [force] [init]',
                        'defaults' => [
                            'controller' => Controller\CliController::class,
                            'action'     => 'remove',
                        ],
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

And my Controller that has method removeAction()

```
namespace Controller;

class CliController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function removeAction()
    {
        $this->logger->debug('I am in');
    }
}
```

When i do command `php public/index.php remove force` or `php public/index.php remove`
I never get sent to do controller and there is no error or any output. So am I doing the matching wrong?

It's like app is not realizing it was called from terminal. Sometimes it just returns `html` if i remove `getConfig` method from `Module.php` within my `module/MyModulefolder`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was that i didn't include `'Zend\Mvc\Console'` in `modules.config.php` so that's way it wasn't reacting when it was given a command from console.

After putting this into array in `modules.config.php` everything is working.

Rookie mistake.

Comment: In my case I had to install zend-console before and add to module.config.php as you said. To install use composer require zendframework/zend-mvc-console

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly my problem.